# Enabling WiFi HotSpot in Google Nexus S

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s, wifi-tethering

I have a Google Nexus S with Android 2.3 in it. I want to tether/or enable Wifi HotSpot in it. 
Do I have to root my phone?

How should I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `Settings->Wireless and Networks->Tethering & portable hotspot`?

Comment: Yes, I have this option. But when I did that the wireless connected gadgets to my phone didnt have the access to the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to have your phone rooted to enable a portable hotspot.

Not quite sure why it isn't working for you, but here are the reasons it hasn't worked for me at various times.

1. No cell data connection. I've tried using the hotspot as a relay to another wi-fi network without any success. The original wi-fi connection is shut down.
2. Misconfigured wi-fi security on the attaching devices.

Comment: Do I need to enable HotSpot through Sprint? Because that is another $20/month :(

Comment: My first thought is no, but I bought my phone from Best Buy without a plan. I can activate the Hot Spot if I bought the old day pass from T-Mobile or switch for the day to T-Mobile's $2/day data plan. I've been able to turn on the Hot Spot on demo phones at various cellular providers when I've fiddled with their phones. But, if Sprint has modified the Android OS, you may have to buy the Sprint package. I'm just not sure. You'll need that answer from someone who has the Google Nexus S from Sprint. Did either of my suggestions help?

Comment: Hey Richard, I downloaded EasyTehter App from the market place and connected to my PC via USB cable through my phone, it worked like a charm. But when I am enabling HotSpot through my phone settings then it does not work. Any clues whats going on?